# Pagination to dynamic data

Tags: angular, angular-material, paginator

I have a service call where I get data from the HTTP request, now the data comes with count and the response, every time response has a count of 10 but in actual, the data is more than 10 like 50 which needs pagination, means backend sends paginated data
I am using mat-paginator in mat-table to show the pagination, it shows the data with 10 lists but for remaining the pagination doesn't work

```
 <mat-paginator
      hidePageSize
      [length]="count"
      [pageSize]="pageSize"
      (page)="onPaginationChange($event)"
    >
    </mat-paginator>
```

any idea on how to do this?

```
data: {
count: 44
result: [,…]
}
```

this is what I am getting

```
   public count: number;
   public memberList: ITeamMember[];
   public pageSize: number;

public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IMemberList> = new MatTableDataSource<
    IMemberList
  >();
  private sort: MatSort;
  private paginator: MatPaginator;

  @ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.isDataLoading = true;
    this.createTeamMemberList();
  }

  private setDataSourceAttributes(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }

public createTeamMemberList(): void {
    this.teamService.getTeamMembers().subscribe(
      (response: TeamMemberResponse) => {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IMemberList>(
          this.individualMember
        );
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.pageSize = response.result.length;
        this.count = response.count;
      },
      (error: Error) => {
        this.isDataLoading = true;
        this.sharedService.openErrorSnackBar(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

[image: a]

Comment: what is count ? Where are u assinging your data.count to this count?. Why is there a membersCount?

Comment: assign `data.count` returned by service to `membersCount` variable and use `[length]="membersCount"` in `<mat-paginator>` ,it should solve your problem.

Comment: [length]="membersCount"

this.membersCount = response.count;

still not working

Comment: @pc_coder count is the total number of entries which are needed to be paginated and in result, there is the data with 10 entries